# How to access AddressListType from RDOAddressList instance?

Tags: mapi, outlook-redemption

I have an RDOAddressList instance (outlook redemption) and I need to know whether it is a public or personal address list.

There is a solution that uses AddressList from Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook package. The property AddressListType is used to decide whether we have a personal (OlAddressListType.olOutlookAddressList) or public (anything else) list. This solution sometimes shows Outlook Security prompt. So it was decided to use the Redemption library to avoid that.

It looks like either it could be possible to get AddressList instance from RDOAddressList or get access to the address list type via the MAPIProp interface of redemption. Neither of these solutions is obvious from the documentation.

Comment: Are you trying to find out if it is a GAL or a Contacts folder based address list?

Comment: There are address lists defined by Exchange administrator, that are available to all users (public), and lists that are defined by the user, that is running our application, in their outlook or via outlook web app which are available only to this user (personal). I need to distinguish between the two types. In plain Interop I did the following: `var isPersonal = list.AddressListType == OlAddressListType.olOutlookAddressList;`. Now I have no access to AddressListType property via the RDOAddressList interface.

Comment: Just wondering if all "public" lists are accessible via GAL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `RDOAddressList.GetContactFolder()` - if it retrovirus an non-null value, the list comes from one of the Outlook's contact folder rather than GAL.